# Is it possible to connect a property to an embedded component

Tags: delphi, ide, components, embed, design-time

I'd like to write a complex component that embeds other components. But I am not sure if I'll be able to connect to those components via object inspector.

To clarify, imagine a component that holds a list of `TDataSources`. These DataSource components are owned by this component and not visible on the form.

Now I'd like to connect a `TDataset` to one of these Datasources, is that possible, will these Datasources show up in the property editor combo of Dataset ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but you have to type (or copy) the name; you cannot select it in the OI.

Using the component written below, you can type e.g. `MyComp1.InternalDataSource` into the `DataSource` property of a DBGrid:

```
uses
  Classes, DB;

type
  TMyComp = Class(TComponent)
  private
    FDataSource: TDataSource;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent);override;
  published
    property DataSource: TDataSource read FDataSource;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('TEST', [TMyComp]);
end;

{ TMyComp }

constructor TMyComp.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FDataSource := TDataSource.Create(Self);
  FDataSource.Name := 'InternalDataSource';
end;
```

Comment: That property setting will not be saved/streamed to the DFM, so you have to set it every time you open the form in the designer and you still need to set it at runtime.

Comment: object DBEdit1: TDBEdit
    Left = 40
    Top = 128
    Width = 121
    Height = 21
    DataField = 'Name'
    DataSource = MyComp1.InternalDataSource
    TabOrder = 0
  end
will be stored , the assignment to a surfacedataset is just for testing, assumed to be part of the component.

Comment: Yes, this is more on topic, and a good example, sadly the ability to use ObjectInspector is crucial, so I'll have to figure out a different strategy, but I'll accept the answer anyway, as it answers the question in the title, and the answer is no (at least not via OI)